# How can I grab a textfield value in Ext.Net?

Tags: c#, ext.net

I know there's a lot of information on this, but mine doesn't seem to be working out so well. I have a form that's created in C# in a form panel. My textfields are created like below:

```
Ext.Net.Panel panel = new Ext.Net.Panel();
Field field = null;
field = new TextField();
field.Name = "FieldTitle";
field.ID = "FieldID";
panel.Add(field);
this.searchform.Add(panel);
this.searchform.Add(new Ext.Net.Button()
{
Text = "Search",
Handler = "getID();"
});
```

When the search button is hit, then a JavaScript function is called which performs a store reload:

```
Ext.getCmp("#Gridpanel").getStore().reload({});
```

On the reload, I want to read the form fields and use the text for another part of the code. However, the below code doesn't seem to be working:

```
if(X.isAjaxRequest){
var ctrl = X.GetCmp<TextField>("FieldID");
string value = ctrl.Value.ToString();
}
```

I can get inside the 'if' statement, but ctrl comes back as null. Is there something else I need to include to grab the text field data?

**EDIT**

So I'm realizing that I'll have to pass an array of the search field ID's to a JavaScript function, then send a dataset back to the server side in order to implement the search. Just to throw it out there, is there a way to dynamically create controls (ie; a TextField) in C# and then get the value from those controls after an event is fired (ie; a button click)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the textfield using 
`Ext.getCmp("#FieldID")` or `X.getCmp("#FieldID")`. `FieldID` is the client ID for `TextField`.

Use developer Tools to check the ID for the TextField

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. The ID in developer Tools shows MainContent_FieldID-inputEl, but the below line brings back null.

var ctrl = X.getCmp("#MainContent_FieldID-inputEl");

Comment: Okay Just get the field using JS code document.getElementById("#MainContent_FieldID-inputEl")

Comment: The problem with that is that I need to grab the field data and then throw it into a C# method so that I can return the text to search for. X.Call to execute JS code won't allow me to return a result to the back end.